# Does the use of an IEC line connector on equipment require a UL cert?

Tags: mains, iec

My client wants to use a 12V SLA with a built-in line-powered charger in his gear. If I add an IEC AC mains line connector does this turkey now have to go through cert?

Comment: Depends on how you plan to use and sell it. UL is not a legal requirement, it’s mainly mandated by insurance companies and vendors.

Comment: The rules are country specific.  UL is normally related to insurance.  Consumer safety standards are different, for instance CE in Europe.